# Why is this JavaFX player freezing?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to use the following player:

```java
public class JavaFXPlayer extends Application {
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private Media media;

  public JavaFXPlayer(String strUrl) {
    this.media = new Media(strUrl);
  }
  public void play() {
    Application.launch();
  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

    // by setting this property to true, the audio will be played
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Playing Audio");
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
      mediaPlayer.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Which I then run like this:

```java
JavaFXPlayer player = new JavaFXPlayer(strUrl);
player.play();
```

However, my whole program freezes instantly when I run `player.play()`. Why is that?

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling `Application.launch()` from within your `Application` class - it should only be called from the `main` method of the program. What were you trying to achieve when  calling `play`?

Comment: I want to run the code in `start` so it plays music.

Comment: If I try to run `Application.launch()` from my program I get an error telling me the is not a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`. Hence why I put the call in my `Application` class.

Comment: Launching this as the application class should not work: `Application.launch` requires an constructor taking no parameters to exist...

Comment: You should not be instantiating `JavaFXPlayer` yourself. Also, the `Application` subclass must have a public **no-arg** constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When launching a JavaFX application via `Application#launch` the runtime creates an instance of the `Application` subclass for you through reflection. This places some constraints on the implementation:

- It must be a `public` class.
- It must have a `public`, no-argument constructor.
- If using modules then its package must be exported to at least the `javafx.graphics` module.

If you use your `Application` subclass as the main class of the application then you don't need a main method—at least not for JavaFX versions 8-12<sup>1</sup>. If you do have a main method it should look something like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception { ... }

}
```

You could also have some other class function as the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Whichever you choose to use you must still have a public, no-argument constructor. This means you lose the ability to pass in the `Media` URL through the constructor. It's not clear where this URL is coming from either. If the URL is coming from the command line arguments then you can access those from the `Application` instance (e.g. inside `start(Stage)` or `init()`) via `Application#getParameters()`. If the URL is hard-coded you'll just have to use it differently (e.g. directly in the `Application` subclass).

All that said, I'm not entirely sure why your application *freezes* as you did not provide a minimal reproducible example. However, the thread calling `Application#launch` is blocked in that method call until the JavaFX runtime exits. This means it's possible you're blocking the *JavaFX Application Thread* if you call that method on said thread.

---

<sup>1. JavaFX has special treatment which allows the main method to be omitted so long as the main class is an implementation of `Application`. However, with the removal of JavaFX from the JDK in version 11, this functionality may be removed in a future release.</sup>